# Como apagar variáveis definidas no Gerenciador de Cabeçalho em uma determinada requisição HTTP (JMETER)

Tags: regex, variáveis, jmeter

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Eu gostaria de apagar um determinado parâmetro (variável) informado no Gerenciados de Cabeçalhos HTTP em apenas uma Requisição HTTP.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Adicione [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)  como um filho da sua requisição HTTP
2. Coloque o seguinte código dento da  "Script" area

   ```
   sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed('foo')
   ```

**Substitua `foo` com o nome do cabeçalho, que você deseja remover.**

[image: JMeter Remove Header From Header Manager]

Mais informações em:

- [HeaderManager.removeNamedHeader()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/HeaderManager.html#removeHeaderNamed-java.lang.String-)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Olá @Dmitri. Está no **SOpt**, pf coloque a sua resposta em português.